# Windows metro apps not working after renaming default user account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, modern-ui

I just renamed my main user (belongs to administrators), and now many metro apps including the Store-App won't open. The outer border appears but then they crash and disappear. A second user that I created afterwards doesn't have this problem. So something is broken in my main user account.

Those are the error logged in the event viewer:

Error (Event-ID: 1000)

```
Faulting application name: WinStore.Mobile.exe, version: 11602.1.26.0, time stamp: 0x5721ad5a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.306, time stamp: 0x571af331
Exception code: 0x00000004
Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f28
Faulting process id: 0x157c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1c686623b758c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_11602.1.26.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.Mobile.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 97162e8a-33a6-423a-9c83-0a3169cb9080
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.WindowsStore_11602.1.26.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Information (Event-ID: 1000)

```
Fault bucket 133327144098, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.WindowsStore_11602.1.26.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
P2: praid:App
P3: 11602.1.26.0
P4: 5721ad5a
P5: KERNELBASE.dll
P6: 10.0.10586.306
P7: 571af331
P8: 00000004
P9: 0000000000071f28
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\oldname\AppData\Local\Temp\WER84B2.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Window_709857eaafaf282f5879e956d8d2e20d83d7bd6_80315bdc_14ac882d

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 97162e8a-33a6-423a-9c83-0a3169cb9080
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 67af441ade053206b627db4c2452d724
```

and Error (Event-ID: 5973)

```
Activation of app Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

Also, I have no idea where I could find this "Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log", mentioned in the third error report. Anyone having any idea? I don't want to create a new user account and switch everything over.

EDIT: Hm, I wanted to give the suggested solutions a shot today. But apparently the problem went away? I have no explanation for this. I have never encountered a problem like this going away on its own in almost 20 years PC experience. I am sorry, I cannot try any of your solutions now to not break the system (again). Still, thank you everyone for your effort. It is well appreciated!

Comment: If you name it back to its original name does it still happen?

Comment: Yes. Even with the old name the error happens now. Also, I don't have a restore point.

Comment: How did you rename the main user account? I.e. did you use Windows 10's **User Accounts > Change your account name** feature or some other way?

Comment: I used netplwiz -> Username -> Properties and changed the name there. I don't know why, but I didn't find the other options to rename a user account. Probably that was the mistake. I will try the suggested solutions in the coming days.

Answer (score 3):

Try this procedure :

1. Run the `Services` applet and stop the service `tiledatamodelsvc`
2. Delete the folder `C:/Users/<your-name>/AppData/Local/TileDataLayer`.
   (or rather rename it first).

This should fix everything immediately, but reboot if no improvement.

If still no improvement, run the [Microsoft troubleshooter for Windows apps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps).

If this also fails, try to create a new user account, assure that the problem
does not occur under this account, then transfer its `TileDataLayer` folder
to your account.
This procedure is detailed in the article
[Fix Windows 10 Start Button Problems](http://www.urtech.ca/2015/09/solved-fix-windows-10-start-button-does-nothing-in-10-minutes/).

Answer (score 2):

***Reinstall Windows Metro Apps***

Maybe reinstalling the apps can help solving this problem.**I suggest to make a restore point before doing this, in case anything goes wrong.** To remove all apps, open an elevated powershell-console(right click --> run as administrator) and run the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers| Remove-AppxPackage
```

To reinstall them, open an elevated powershell-console and run the following command:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"
```

Please Note: Maybe there will be some errors when reinstalling the apps, you can savely ignore them. If reinstall won't work try to get full access to the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ Folder as mentioned here: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/

Also note that a reboot could be required after reinstalling the apps.

**Repair corrupt Windows system files**

Another option would be to repair windows system files with sfc and dism. To do this, open an elevated command prompt and run the following command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

It can take up to 3 runs for sfc to replace all corrupt files. If you still see this error after the 3. run:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them
```

open an elevated command prompt and run the following command:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

**Please note: DISM will stay for 5-10 Minutes on 20%. This is a normal behavior. Don't try to stop DISM via CTRL + C or closing the Command Prompt**

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

**Make a backup of registry before going forward.**

1. Open **Registry Editor** and make a backup.
2. Scroll all the way down to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage`.
3. Find `winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy` subkey under `Storage`. If one's not there, create it.
4. If you had created `winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy` key, go ahead and create 2 more keys named `Internet Settings` and `Software` under `winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy`. In case they had been already there, delete the keys under `Internet Settings` and `Software`.
5. Go [here](https://helgeklein.com/download/#) and download EXE version of **SetACL** (it's a tool to manage Windows permissions from the command line).
6. Open Command Prompt with administrative privileges and run

   ```
   SetACL -on "hkcu\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n: S-1-15-2-2608634532-1453884237-1118350049-1925931850-670756941-1603938316-3764965493;p:full;i:so,sc;m:grant;w:dacl"
   ```

If you like to know what this does, please refer to [SetACL documentation](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/).

7. Restart computer. Now probably apps should work.